# Navigation error in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I'm just a newbie for this program language and I made a mini project about it. Can anyone out there tell me what I will do for this error?! first it works well but when I Click the other tab it will not process and this will be the error..

[image]

```
Class1 ob = new Class1();
ob.dt = (DataTable)Session["cart"];
string str = "";

if (ob.dt.Rows.Count == 0 )
{
    str = "_______________________________";

    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
    str = "No Item Selected";
    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
    str = "_______________________________";
    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
}
else
{
    str = "    " + "Product  " + "Quantity";
    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
    str = "_______________________________";
    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
    int index = 1;

    for (int j = 0; j <= ob.dt.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        DataRow dr = ob.dt.Rows[j];
        str = Convert.ToString(index) + ". " + Convert.ToString(dr["pname"]) 
        +"" + Convert.ToString(dr["qty"]);
        ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
        index++;
    }
    int total = Class2.gettotalprice();

    str = "_______________________________";
    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
    str = "Total Amount=  " + total.ToString();

    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
}
```

After Changing the data to not null there will have again a new error which will occur in this line

```
for (int j = 0; j <= ob.dt.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
{
    DataRow dr = ob.dt.Rows[j];
    str = Convert.ToString(index) + ". " + Convert.ToString(dr["pname"]) 
    +"" + Convert.ToString(dr["qty"]);
    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
    index++;
}
```

Take a look to this screenshot

[image]

Comment: Seems that ob / dt is null, would you mind to post some code?

Comment: Okay I will .. just a minute ..

Comment: public Class1()
        {
            dt = new DataTable("cart");
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns["id"].AutoIncrement = true;
            dt.Columns["id"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            dt.Columns.Add("pid", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("pname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add("price", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add("img", typeof(string));
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

Comment: there will be the error occur

Class1 ob = new Class1();
            ob.dt = (DataTable)Session["cart"];
            string str = "";
            
            if (ob.dt.Rows.Count == 0 )
            {
                str = "_______________________________";

                ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
                str = "No Item Selected";
                ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
                str = "_______________________________";
                ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
            }
            else
            {

Comment: stop pasting your code in comment, it is hard to impossible to read. Edit the question to include those codes instead.

Comment: @user3247143- Please edit your Question ... and put all this in that

Comment: @user3247143 have you tried replacing your condition with the one I posted below?

Comment: You are getting the second error because you didn't check for nulls again. Did you not learn anything from what I posted? You can't operate on null objects!

Comment: @user3247143 seems that the ob is null... is it because of Session["cart"] is null?, would you consider checking if the session is null first?

Answer (score 1):

You should always check to make sure the objects you are operating on are not null.

This will prevent you from getting the null reference error on that line if you replace your condition with the one below:

```
if (ob != null && ob.dt != null && ob.dt.rows != null && ob.dt.rows.Count == 0)
```

Either your `ob` or your `dt` object is `null`. Look for the line of code where you are assigning these object or setting them and see why they are `null`. When they are null you can't invoke methods or access properties on that objects because you have no instance of that class. Somewhere in your code you set either `ob` or `dt` to null. Or you never instantiate them but I doubt that is it. It looks more like you aren't returning any records from a repository you are trying to access or something.

EDIT:

You are seeing your second issue because again you aren't checking for NULL objects. You can wrap your for loop up in a null check but I can't tell you everywhere in your program that you will have to null check.

```
if (ob != null && ob.dt != null && ob.dt.rows != null)
 {
          for (int j = 0; j <= ob.dt.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                DataRow dr = ob.dt.Rows[j];
                str = Convert.ToString(index) + ". " + Convert.ToString(dr["pname"]) 
            +"" + Convert.ToString(dr["qty"]);
                ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
                index++;
            }
 }
```

Comment: and just take look at this code 

public Class1()
        {
            dt = new DataTable("cart");
            dt.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns["id"].AutoIncrement = true;
            dt.Columns["id"].AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
            dt.Columns.Add("pid", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("pname", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("qty", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add("price", typeof(Int32));
            dt.Columns.Add("img", typeof(string));
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

Comment: @user3247143 Please put the code in the question and format it in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Check first that the data is not null before using it, like this:

```
if (ob.dt == null)
{
    //handle here
    return;
}

//and your code goes here
if (ob.dt.Rows.Count == 0 )
{
    str = "_______________________________";

    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
    str = "No Item Selected";
    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
    str = "_______________________________";
    ListBox1.Items.Add(str);
}
.....
```

Comment: of course that will be the best solution, and of course Session["cart"] is the culprit here. My suggested solution can be used so that you will not get an error, //handle here comment can be used to handle the NullReference though.

Comment: though what kind of handling it will be?

Comment: The answer to "Where does Session["cart"] came from?" is the answer to your ^question. XD